# Issue with facebook share functionality

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following page : http://danone.staging-eurorscg.com.au/blackcherry-and-chocolate

When I use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ and fetch new scrap information their are no errors or warnings and below is what I see which is correct :

[image]

I've cleared my cache and refreshed the page numerous times, but when I go to page mentioned above and click share I see the complete opposite :

[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that the "Share" button uses the sharer.php functionality which allows to specify the URL of shared page (not automatically the current URL). The thing is that the URL specified in the button is http://danone.staging-eurorscg.com.au/flavour-lab, not the current one.